# Laravel Backup to Cloud programming

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api, cloud, backup, dropbox-api

I currently own an application developed in Laravel 5.5 deployed in a shared hosting service.

I need to implement an automated backup system with these features:

- Run automatically (cron) every day (ideally cron laravel)
- Include (laravel files, uploaded files (storage / app) and database)
- Copy the backup to the cloud as a final step (Dropbox, Goggle Dive for example)

Is there any recommendation on how to do this for a Laravel application?

I guess there are different alternatives

- From a unix script (I'm not an expert)
- An application in PHP
- The one that I think would be ideal is to add the code within the same Laravel application and use Laravel's own cron

But I do not know if it's possible from laravel

- Compress files
- Backup the database
- Upload files to the cloud

I accept ideas and recommendations, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you searched for any package for backup... here is one i am currenlty using and is working fine for me for local backups and has scheduling feature as well, you can explore more...

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup

Comment: Really very interesting. I'm going to investigate it. You know if it is possible to leave the backup in Google Drive. From what I see Laravel has a driver for Dropbox, but not for Google Drive.

Comment: check this link they are discussing something relevant.. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/468

Comment: Hi. It works. I used this tutorial to configure Google Driver https://gist.github.com/sergomet/f234cc7a8351352170eb547cccd65011 and I put de google id folder in local too 'name' => '1ibtk0QiroA4yErNjZqncaYQ3oxx5YETl', //config('app.name') Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to use spatie/laravel-backup to server backup?